# Fastest way to convert lists into plain text?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to convert a series of lists into one single line of text separated by a blank space

```
def Function(lists):
    Numbers= str(len(lists))+ " "
    for item in lists:
        for items in item:
            Numbers = Numbers + str(items) +'  ' 
    print Numbers

Data = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]
Function(Data)
```

this should return "2 1 2 3 10 20 30"
However this approach is very slow.

is there a way to do this faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new string on every `+` operator, which is horribly slow(when applied a lot). Instead use a generator expression with `str.join`:

```
In [11]: from itertools import chain

In [12]: data = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]

In [13]: " ".join(str(i) for i in chain(*data))
Out[13]: '1 2 3 10 20 30'
```

Edit:

And you can append the list length with and method you want, since it doesn't affect performance much:

```
" ".join((str(len(data)), " ".join(str(i) for i in chain(*data)))
```

Edit2:

[hcwhsa pointed out that generator expression has no advantage with `str.join`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892). So you may want to use a list comprehension instead of generator expression.

Comment: [A generator expression has no performance/memory advantage when used with `str.join`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892).

Comment: I thought that is trivial. Added.

Comment: @hcwhsa, I didn't know that `str.join` needs two passes over argument, thank you.

Comment: But as hcwsa mentions in my question, he wants the length of the list as the first element to the string :P

Answer (score 2):

This was the simplest to me:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]
>>> " ".join([str(item) for var in data for item in var])
'1 2 3 10 20 30'
```

So you can write your function like so:

```
def fun(data):
    return " ".join([str(item) for var in data for item in var])
```

I do not know if this was a mistake on your behalf, but if you want to add the length of the list as the first number, then you can do the following:

```
def fun(data):
    return str(len(data)) + ' ' + " ".join([str(item) for var in data for item in var])
```

Comment: Expected output is `"2 1 2 3 10 20 30"`.

Comment: @hcwhsa I think thats a mistake.

Comment: I don't think so, see: `Numbers= str(len(lists))+ " "`

Comment: @hcwhsa You're right. Still quite weird, don't you think? Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

please consider to use `join` method of string

```
def Function(lists):
    data = " ".join(j for i in lists for j in i))
    return " ".join([len(lists), data])
```